# How do I use Openfire with OpenLDAP and ldap.clientSideSorting?

Tags: openldap, openfire

The system log on my Openfire + OpenLDAP installation is getting flooded with this message:

```
slap_global_control: unrecognized control: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.473
```

This means that Openfire wants OpenLDAP to do server-side sorting, which OpenLDAP doesn't support. The [Openfire LDAP Guide](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/ldap-guide.html) advises to set the property *ldap.clientSideSorting* to *true* in this case.

Unfortunately, Openfire doesn't find any user accounts in LDAP anymore if I do that. How do I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the [slap-valsort(5)](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/overlays.html#Value%20Sorting) overlay.

I haven't used it myself but the Audit Logging, Dynamic Groups and Reverse Group Membership Maintenace weren't too much of a hassle to set up, so you might want to give it a try.